# Xtext: How to persist a DSL AST using XMI (or JSON)?

Tags: xtext, language-server-protocol

I'm currently trying to figure out how to "connect" an Xtext Language Server with an EMFCloud.ModelServer instance so each time a client (VS Code extension in my case) saves a custom DSL text file, the Language Server saves the AST as `XMI` (or `JSON`). So then later the model can be included in the Model Server workspace and other editors can react to changes on my model (`XMI`, `JSON`)

So far I've seen that the current Xtext LS version does nothing with the "textDocument/didSave" notifications:

```
@Override
public void didSave(DidSaveTextDocumentParams params) {
    // nothing to do
}
```

I'd like to enhance my LS instance to provide logic to that method and persist the current AST to `XMI/JSON`.

So far I was able to see that there is a `generator` class which the `doGenerate` method is called when the save is triggered on client side. However, taking a look to the call hierarchy of that method, it seems that is called within a "code generation" process. The documentation found for this is always related to other language generation (i.e. `Java` or `c++`) and I'm not sure if this would be the right place also because it seems that the file URI is not accessible (as it is in the `didSave` method of the LS part)

As summary, is there a way to access the semantic model (AST) from the Language Server "didSave" operation?

Comment: you can also implement a command and do it there. i also dont understand the `the file URI is not accessible` thing. in IGenerator2 you have a resource as a param. you can ask it for its uri

Comment: Hi @ChristianDietrich, thanks for the comment, could you elaborate more about what do you mean with "implement a command"?

Comment: there is the concept of commands in lsp https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specifications/specification-current/#command

Comment: @ChristianDietrich I see. Currently we're not interested in adding new command "calls" in the client server communication. I've added a summary question because is still not clear how to access the current semantic model from the Language Server (instead of doing that from the generator). I've found a very old post http://koehnlein.blogspot.com/2010/06/semantic-model-access-in-xtext.html but seems that the API changed.

Comment: you can call a do read as it is done at 10s of places in LanguageServerImpl

Answer (score 0):

Following the hints provided by [Christian Dietrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/935687/christian-dietrich), the Language Server uses a `ProjectManager` which is able to retrieve the `XtextResource` holding the semantic model for a specific model URI (i.e. the URI passed to the server from the editor). Basically:

```
XtextResource resource = (XtextResource) getWorkspaceManager().getProjectManager(uri).getResource(uri);
```

In order to get our model from the resource the following method is provided:

```
EList<EObject> modelObjects = resource.getContents();
```

At this point we can persist the semantic model via the EMF Model Server (i.e. by creating or modifying an existing model in the Model Server).